# is it true that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$, there's only one way to factorize 22 into irreducibles?(ignoring permutation and associates)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-writing

for a specific example $22$, it seems to me that the only way to factorize it into irreducibles is $(-2)(\sqrt{-11})(\sqrt{-11})$ and indeed these are irreducibles. And I can manage to show that there's no way we can factorize 22 into products of the form $(a+b\sqrt{-11})(a-b\sqrt{-11})$ since there's no integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy this equation. But then it got me thinking that if there are any other ways to factorize $22$ into products of three,four or even more.

1.for $22$ is my derivation correct? (there's only one way to factorize $22$ into irreducibles in this ring if we ignoring permutations and associates)

2.how do we formalize the proof that there's no other ways $22$ can be factorized into irreducibles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I do think my question is crystal clear

Comment: The question in the title is different from the questions in  the body of the post, so it is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: $12 = (1+ \sqrt{-11})(1-\sqrt{-11}) = 2 \times 2 \times 3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt
12? yeh I can manage to show that, but for 22, is there any other way to factorize it into product of irreducibles other that above?(ignoring permutations and associates)

Comment: The usual way to solve problems like this is to use the multiplicative norm $N(a+b\sqrt{-11}) = a^2+11b^2$ for $a,b \in {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: what does that have to do with determining factorizations of the element into irreducibles?

Comment: Write $22 = \prod_{j=1}^J a_j$ with $a_j$ irreducible.

$\sqrt{-11}$ is a prime element which divides $22$ so it must divide one of the $a_j$, wlog $a_1$, so $22/\sqrt{-11} = (a_1/\sqrt{-11})\prod_{j=2}^J a_j$.

$a_1$ is irreducible so $a_1/\sqrt{-11}$ is a unit.

Again $\sqrt{-11}$ divides the LHS so it must divide one of the $a_j$, wlog it is $a_2$. So $-2 = (a_1/\sqrt{-11})(a_2/\sqrt{-11}) \prod_{j>3}^J a_j$.

$2$ is irreducible so $J=3$ and $a_3/2$ is a unit.

Comment: @reuns
Im so sorry im still trying to understand your reply. But how did you come to the conclusion J=3? also does that mean 22 can only be factorized into product of at most 3 irreducibles? But The ring is not UFD, so the uniqueness is not guaranteed so how do we know if there's any other factorizations into irreducibles or not?

Comment: $22$ has a unique factorization in irreducibles because it is a product of one irreducible with some prime elements.

Comment: @reuns could you elaborate on that pls. Thank you so much!

Comment: @reuns: one would need to prove that $\sqrt{-11}$ is a prime, and not merely an irreducible...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct that this is essentially the only factorization. The usual way of dealing with these questions ad hoc is to use the norm map.

Consider the multiplicative norm map,
$$N\colon\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]\to\mathbb{Z}$$
given by $N(a+b\sqrt{-11}) = a^2+11b^2$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. This map satisfies $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$, and that $x$ is a unit if and only if $N(x)=1$.

In particular, we have that if $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ are such that $x$ divides $y$, then $N(x)$ must divide $N(y)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $N(22) = 22^2 = 2^2\times 11^2$, any factorization of $22$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ must involve factors of norms $2$, $4$, $11$, or $11^2$.

The only solutions to $a^2+11b^2 = 11$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ are $a=0$, $b=\pm 1$, so the only elements with norm $11$ are $\pm\sqrt{-11}$.

There are no solutions to $a^2+11b^2=2$. The only solutions to $a^2+11b^2=4$ are $a=\pm 2$, $b=0$.

The only solutions to $a^2+11b^2=11^2$ are $a=\pm 11$, $b=0$; for $b=\pm1,\pm 2,\pm3$ we have $11^2-11b^2$ is not a square, and $|b|\gt 3$ is impossible.

Thus any nontrivial factorization of $22$ would have to involve a factor of norm $4$, and either two factors of norm $11$ or one factor of norm $11^2$. But $\pm 11$ is not irreducible, since $\pm11 = \mp(\sqrt{-11})^2$. So a factorization into irreducibles must be a product of $\pm 2$ and the square of $\sqrt{-11}$, with appropriate signs.

---

Aside: As it happens, the rings of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with $d=-1$, $-2$, $-3$, $-7$, $-11$, $-19$, $-43$, $-67$, and $-163$, are UFDs, and in fact are the only [quadratic imaginary number fields with that property](https://planetmath.org/listofallimaginaryquadraticextensionswhoseringofintegersisapid). The ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$, however, is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}]$ and not $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$, which is why you cannot invoke unique factorization directly above. However, your factorization happens to be the unique factorization of $22$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}]$, so any other factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ is likewise impossible.

Comment: sorry but how come Z[√-11] is UFD? I remember this conclusion that Z[√-d] for all d>3 is not UFD. Did I misunderstand something in there

Comment: @Jared $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ is not a UFD; it is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}]$ that is a UFD. I had a wrong statement in a previous edit, which as been fixed.

Comment: ah okok thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Jared If you are satisfied with the answer (give it a few hours to see if you get a different answer you like better) be sure to click on the arrow under the voting buttons to formally "accept" the answer, thus indicating that your question/problem has been answered.